# Non ascii characters in URL param in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am using graph API of Facebook and I call it through camel framework. My query has non ASCII characters (e.g. küçük). I am getting the following exception:-

```
Cause: 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException: Invalid query
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.parseUriReference(URI.java:2049)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.<init>(URI.java:147)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.getURI
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod
at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.executeMethod
at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122)
```

Does camel support non ASCII characters in URI? If not, what other things can be done?

```
example URL: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.example.com/küçük
```

Comment: Read about url encoding - its not a Camel specific problem, but the rules of URLs in general.

Comment: @ClausIbsen
I referred to Apache camel document (http://camel.apache.org/book-getting-started.html). In the section "The Meaning of URL, URI, URN and IRI", the document says a camel URI can support letters and digits in the US ASCII character set. Do you know a way in which I can ask camel to use IRI or any other options to support special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what we were able to do to fix the issue.

In Apache Camel, the HTTP_URI component does not accept any special characters, even after encoding them.  This is a bug in Camel which is not yet closed.

Fortunately for us, the special characters would only appear in the Query String of the URL and not the main URI part.  Camel provides another component HTTP_QUERY, which can successfully parse and understand encoded UTF-8 characters.  By setting it in the Header, we were able to get rid of the issue.

So basically first we encode the URL to UTF-8 and then set the HTTP_QUERY value as query string.  This worked like charm.
e.g. (Scala)

```
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, _.in[HttpRequest].uri.split(?).head)
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, _.in[HttpRequest].uri)
```

Comment: Camel does support special characters in the main part of URL. Invalid URI problem occurs when we have special characters in the Query part of URL.

Answer (score 4):

"URL encoding replaces non ASCII characters with a "%" followed by hexadecimal digits." ([more info here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp))

You could try this:

```
URL url = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
```

or maybe

```
String xstr = URLEncoder.encode("维", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this did not help in Apache camel context.

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent(url)` it will work